# Devise, Ransack, and sorting by latest login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ransack

I'm using Devise to manage user logins to my site and Ransack to sort the User index.

I'm using this code to create a link to sort users by latest login:

`<%= sort_link(@q, :current_sign_in_at, 'By latest login', default_order: :desc) %>`

The result is a page which shows the users which have never logged in, sorted by oldest-created account to newest, followed by users who *have* logged in, sorted by most recent login to oldest.

What am I doing wrong? How do I move the users who have never logged in to the end of the queue?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: The problem is `NULL` is neither greater than, less than or equal to anything else, including itself. You may want to do two queries, one sorted by time for those with a non-`NULL` entry, and then one for the `NULL` entries.

Comment: Thanks, tadman! That’s exactly what I thought, but do you know how to coerce Ransack to take this into account? I don’t know how to tell Ransack that it’s making a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an option for Ransack per-se. There's RDBMS specific ways of handling this like `IFNULL()` which can set a default dummy date for sorting purposes, or Postgres with [`NULLS FIRST|LAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-order.html).